# Google font cdn not loading after publishing on Azure

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, azure-web-app-service, google-font-api

I have an application developed in .net MVC and using "SourceSansPro" font.

Imported google font into css as. This is first statement of css file

```
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic);
```

When I run this on local, font are loading correctly but after publishing on Azure,looks like they are not loading.

After inspecting the font on Azure app, font is getting applied but the size is bigger than what it looks on local however all css classes and properties applied are same.

**What Tried -**

- Tried by embedding font in solution directory as well, removed cdn and used embedded fonts. Made required changes for MIME types in web config as below
- Tried by disabling bundling

Can you please guide, where am I doing wrong? 
We wanted to use cdn itself and not embedded font

Comment: What is the error in the network page in the developer tools?

Comment: No eroor, Benni.. All are green, even console doesn't have anything.

Comment: But the font file is loaded in the waterfall diagram?

Comment: Yes, I see that too.. it's loaded under font.google.api.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. @Oxygen did you find a solution?

Comment: not yet @Woodchipper. I will share if i found something, meanwhile if you find any please share urs as well. Thanks!

Comment: I removed cdn and embedded fonts in content folder. It looks good now.

Comment: Same problem here trying to use a Google font in an HTML document that gets rendered as PDF later on. Locally, the PDF ends up using the correct font, once deployed to Azure, not so.